# How to find and resolve the reason for which FF57 forgets some logins?

Tags: firefox

I have updated to Firefox 57, and since then I am having some problems with my logins.

Some sites works fine (SE is one of them), but others I have to login every time I restart Firefox, even if until FF56 I did not need to.

Also LastPass, despite selecting the option to remember me for 30 days, asks me for my secondary OTP every time.

Yes, I clear my history every time I close Firefox, but I was doing so also before, and I have not changed any option. What did change on Firefox side? How can I remain logged in?

This are my history cleaning options, if it helps:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on the Firefox support forums. The [answer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1189970#answer-1038680) seems to be that "offline website data" is now considered an improved version of the cookies, so login details can be stored there.

Deselecting the "offline website data" option solves the problem.